# What are the missing numbers in this table?

Tags: puzzle

Given this table, I try to fill the missing numbers:

[image]

What are the missing numbers?

Comment: This isn't a site for puzzles (there is one, at http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions . If this is a mathematical question, show us what you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it can be custom multiplication table:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathbf{12} &  \mathbf{9} & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{4} & \times \\ \hline
84 & 63 & 14 & 42 & 28 & \mathbf{7} \\ \hline
132 & 99 & 22 & 66 & 44 & \mathbf{11} \\ \hline
96 & 72 & 16 & 48 & 32 & \mathbf{8} \\ \hline
120 & 90 & 20 & 60 & 40 & \mathbf{10} \\ \hline
60 & 45 & 10 & 30 & 20 & \mathbf{5} \\ \hline
\end{array}